# using javascript to modify form action submits form without doing submit

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have an HTML form that I submit after changing the action with some javascript. Two different buttons can do the submit.

The interesting thing is that I was trying to debug it and inserted an alert after changing the action and before submitting the form. The form is submitted without the alert ever being displayed. To make sure it's actually performing the javascript, I added an alert before changing the action.  That alert displays; the alert after changing the action does not.

```
<form name='FormSelect' method='post' action='Undefined'>
...
<button onclick="SubmitForm('class')">Submit</button>
...
<button onclick="SubmitForm('student')">Submit</button>
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitForm(target){
    alert("Action 1: " + document.FormSelect.action);
    if (target=="class") {
        document.FormSelect.action = "ClassAction.php";
    } else {
        document.FormSelect.action = "StudentAction.php";
    }
    alert("Action 2: " + document.FormSelect.action);
 // document.FormSelect.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Is that the expected sequence of events?

Comment: The buttons are already automatically submitting the form - why are you manually submitting a second time? Just change the action and let it go

Comment: Or better. Give the buttons a name each and submit to Actio.php and let the server see the name of the button

Comment: @mplungjan Each button represents a student ID. If I have 20-30 buttons on the form, and the user clicks one of them, is only that button's value passed to the server?

Comment: Yes. Make each a submit button with a name and a value. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Any button placed inside form element will cause submit action. To prevent this you can add type="button" to button elements, or make you submit callback return false;

```
<button type="button" onclick="SubmitForm('class')">Submit</button
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/yD2Uu/

Comment: return SubmitForm(...) - and that will likely cancel the submission all together

Comment: I was questioning why the change of action submits the form instead of continuing on with the next javascript statement. The examples I'd seen show changing the action followed by a submit. It appears that anything after changing the action is not executed.

Comment: I tried adding type=button, but it made no difference. The 2nd alert within the javascript function is not executed; the 1st alert is.

Comment: Yes, type=button will only prevent form from being submit. I'll try to figure it out, why the second alert is not executed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yD2Uu/5/ see this, both alerts are execuded. (tested on firefox 20)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to give the buttons a name each and submit to Action.php and let the server get the value of the named button

```
$student = filter_var($_POST["student"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // php5 cleaning
```

when you have

```
<form method="post" action="Actions.php">
  <input type="submit" name="student" value="John Doe" />
  <input type="submit" name="student" value="Jane Doe" />
  <input type="submit" name="student" value="Whatever Doe" />
</form>
```

Otherwise if you must

Try this

```
<form method='post' action='Undefined'>
...
<input type="button" value="Class" onclick="SubmitForm(this)" />
...
<input type="button" value="Student" onclick="SubmitForm(this)"/>
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var actions = {
  "class":"ClassAction.php",
  "student":"StudentAction.php"
}

function SubmitForm(button){
  button.form.action = actions[button.value];
  button.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already pointed out the form will be submitted anyway if you don't cancle the event. I want to suggest a JavaScript free solution to your problem.

```
<button formaction="ClassAction.php">Submit</button>
<button formaction="StudentAction.php">Submit</button>
```

It's not supported in IE < 10 though. But you can still use your function as a fallback then, just a bit more elegant ;)

```
function SubmitForm(button){
  button.form.action = button.formaction;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the example I gave is simplified code to illustrate the question. The actual code actually only has 1 button, generated by PHP to pass either "class" or "student" to the javascript function. The javascript function uses that parameter to determine which of several actions to take, based on other form input values.

Comment: I see. But that kind of evaluation is usually handled by server side frameworks.

Comment: good point; I'll investigate how to have a PHP script conditionally execute another PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yauhen Vasileusky's example, I started removing code between my 1st & 2nd alerts and found that the problem seems to be the following IF statement:

```
if (document.FormSelect.FormName.value.substr(0,19)=="ObservationRequest_" || document.FormSelect.FormName.value=="StudentReg2013rx" || document.FormSelect.FormName.value=="Toddler Update Form v3rx")
{
document.FormSelect.action = "GenerateXDP.php";
}
```

When I remove it, both alerts are displayed. So the answer to my question is that changing the action does not submit the form; it was some other error in my code that made it appear as if that was the case.